# For all positive integers $a, b, c > 4$ if $(a - 2) (b - 2)(c - 2) = 4(a + b + c) + 4$ then what can be the value of $(a + b + c)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

For all positive integers $a, b, c > 4$ if $(a - 2) (b - 2)(c - 2) = 4(a + b + c) + 4$ then what can be the value of $(a + b + c)$ ?

- 13
- 15
- 20
- None of these

---

Here is my try at the question:
$(a - 2) (b - 2)(c - 2) = 4(a + b + c) + 4$

$ abc -2bc-2ac+4c-2ab+4b+4a-8 = 4a + 4b + 4c +4$

$abc - 2(bc+ac+ab) = 12$

---

However, I don't know how to proceed further. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Given:$$(a - 2)(b - 2)(c - 2) = 4(a + b + c) + 4 $$ where

- $a, b, c > 4 $ and
- $ a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}.$

First, we note that the minimum value of $$a + b + c$$  is 15, which occurs when $$a = b = c = 5.$$ Therefore the option 13 is eliminated.

Now, let's test if $$ a = b = c = 5$$ satisfies the equation:

$$(a - 2)(b - 2)(c - 2) = (5 - 2)(5 - 2)(5 - 2) = 3 \times 3 \times 3 = 27.$$

The right side of the equation for $$a + b + c = 15$$ is:

$$4(a + b + c) + 4 = 4(15) + 4 = 60 + 4 = 64.$$

Since $$27 \neq 64,$$ the equation is not satisfied when $$ a = b = c = 5.$$

Therefore, $$a + b + c = 15$$ is eliminated as a possible value.

You are left with the $20$. It is easy to check with an example you want$$(a - 2)(b - 2)(c - 2)=84$$ (the numbers can only be between $5$ and $10$): if you take $a=5, b=6, c=9$ it works.

Therefore the answer is 20.

Comment: Oh so the question was meant to be solved by eliminating the options. Ohk ohk. However, how do we find that a + b+ c is minimum when a = b = c = 5. I mean to ask for a formal proof actually Anyways +1 I am satisfied by the answer for original question

Comment: Since the integers are >4, then the smallest value they can take is 5, and if the three of them take this value. Then min(a+b+c)=15.
For 20 I am not sure if there's a better way to approach than an example, but you don't have many possibilities that's why I considered it.

Comment: oh yeah thanks bro